# Django administration panel filter list

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-filter

I have my django model: Post

Any Post has an author (User|Admin)

I would to add post's administration in my Django administration panel but I would to show in Posts list ONLY posts with author=Admin.

Is possible this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking I would say that it's better to create a custom view for this purpose (in a public section of the site). But if you prefer to use admin then you can try [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method. For example if you want to show all posts to admins and their own posts for simple users it would be smth like this (copied from official docs link above):

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PostAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```